# Running multiple projects but separate output in Visual Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Code provides the concept of compounds configuration to launch multiple processes. However, all this processes log into one single Debug Console. This is quite ugly. Is there any possibility to have one output windows/tab/something for each process that is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using task configuration (tasks.json) you can set the `panel` attribute inside `presentation`. It controls if the panel is shared between tasks, dedicated to this task or a new one is created on every run:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo Hello",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

By default is `shared` but you can have `dedicated` or `new`